# Do we get a field when we form the quotient ring of polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$ modulo polynomials that annihilate $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, solution-verification, ideals

Let $\alpha = \sqrt2+\sqrt3$. Prove that $I =\{f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x] : f(\alpha) = 0\}$ is a nontrivial principal ideal in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Discuss if $\mathbb{Q}[x]/I$ is a field.

This is my solution:

If $\alpha = \sqrt2+\sqrt3$, then $\alpha^{4}-10\alpha^{2}+1 = 0$. Thus $\alpha$ is a root of the polynomial $p(x) = x^{4}-10x^{2}+1 \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$. We now consider the map $\phi_{\alpha}: \mathbb{Q}[x] \to \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ extending the identity in $\mathbb{Q}$ and sending $x \mapsto \alpha$ (ie, the evaluation map). Then $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism, and  it induces an isomorphism $\mathbb{Q}[x]/Ker(\phi_{\alpha})  \cong Im (\phi_{\alpha})$. We now prove that $Ker(\phi_{\alpha}) = I$. First, for every $f(x) \in I$ we have $f(\alpha) = 0$, therefore $f(x) \in Ker(\phi_{\alpha})$. In other words, $I \subset Ker(\phi_{\alpha})$. To see the inclusion in the other direction, suppose that $f(x) \in Ker(\phi_{\alpha})$, then $f(\alpha) = 0$ and $f(x) \in I$. It follows that $Ker(\phi_{\alpha}) = I$. Hence, $I$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Moreover, $\phi_{\alpha}$ is surjective, for, $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ of dimension 4, a basis is $\{1, \alpha, \alpha^{2}, \alpha^{3}\}$. Thus, every element in $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ can be written uniquely as $a + b\alpha + c\alpha^{2}+d\alpha^{3} = \phi_{\alpha} (a + bx + cx^{2}+dx^{3}) \in Im(\phi_{\alpha})$ (for some $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{Q}$. Hence, we get an isomorphism $\mathbb{Q}[x]/I \cong \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$. Since $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ is a field, the quotient $\mathbb{Q}[x]/I$ is also a field and $I$ is a maximal ideal generated by a unique monic polynomial of minimal degree. This is: $I = (x^{4}-10x^{2}+1)$

I´ve also though about a more hands-on argument showing that $x^{4}-10x^{2}+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ and, since $\mathbb Q[x]$ is a PID, the ideal $(x^{4}-10x^{2}+1)$ is prime and hence maximal, which implies that $\mathbb{Q}[x]/I$ is a field. I´ve tried modig out by $3$ but it factors as $(x^{2}+1)^{2}$. However if I assume for the sake of contradiction that it factors as

$$x^{4}-10x^{2}+1 = (x^{2}+ax+1)(x^{2}+bx+1)$$

I get that $a=\sqrt12, b = -\sqrt12$ which implies that it is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Comment: This seems correct, except the fact that $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ is a field (i.e. $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$) is slightly non-trivial. Make sure you know the proof of this fact.

Comment: Do you mean for this specific $\alpha$ or any in general? I know that the proof uses the correspondence between ideals containing $(p(x))$ and ideals in the quotient. If such polynomial is irreducible, then ithe ideal it generates is maximal and the quotient can only contain the trivial ideals, and that characterizes fields.

Comment: Ok, it seems I have overcomplicated the question. $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ since $(p(x))$ is maximal, and this proof is correct. I mean $\alpha$ here by the specific value $\alpha = \sqrt2+\sqrt3$.